# Is there a way to further reduce ''the for loop'' in this python code?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I want to make a new list from the existing list such that each element in the new list is the product of all the numbers in the existing list except the element in the same position of a new list element.

For example [2,4,5] --> [20,10,8]

I came up with a solution wherein one for-loop, j traverses to the right side of the i-th (current) element while in other for loop, k covers the left side of the elements - Multiplies and gives the result.

```
def mulList():
    oldList = [2,4,5]
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(oldList)):
        a = 1
        for j in range(i+1,len(oldList)):
            a *= oldList[j] 
        for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
            a *= oldList[j] 
        newList.append(a)
    print(newList)
mulList()
```

Later I got to know that we can solve it with two for-loops like this where I am not doing anything if i equals j

```
def mulList():
    oldList = [2,4,5]
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(oldList)):
        a = 1
        for j in range(len(oldList)):
            if j == i:
                a += 0
            else:
                a *= oldList[j] 
        newList.append(a)
    print(newList)
mulList()
```

I was wondering whether there is any better way to solve it with only one for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just multiply everything together once, and then loop through the elements again and divide the total product with the current element:

```
def mulList():
    oldList = [2,4,5]
    newList = []
    total = 1
    for x in oldList:
        total *= x  # total = total * x
    for x in oldList:
        # Use // to get int (4) instead of float (4.0)
        newList.append(total // x)
    print(newList)
```

Comment: It would be good to add, why your code (which is significantly different from original) is the same as OP. Otherwise it's easy to get lost.

Comment: For integer input, the division should use `//` instead of `/` to ensure you get ints out instead of floats.

Comment: Thanks...Nice to think it this way, but my aim is to reduce the for-loop

Comment: you need atleast one for loop anyways @DishantMewada to iterate over your elements, you cannot element them altogether

Comment: @DishantMewada This is the best there is, you will have to iterate through all the elements twice anyways. But notice how the for loops aren't inside each other anymore; we're now iterating over the elements twice, instead of iterating over all the elements during each element. So instead of `len(oldList) * len(oldList)` operations, we are now doing `2 * len(oldList)` operations.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes exactly, I only want one for-loop. while in my first code I am using three for-loops and other code - two for-loops

Comment: sure, In my answer @DishantMewada , I replaced one for loop with functools.reduce, which essentially is a reduce operation on the list, but internally can be thought of as another for loop, not sure if that's what you are loooking for

Comment: @DishantMewada What's the reason for wanting to avoid `for` loops so badly? There's nothing wrong with using for loops, and you shouldn't try to avoid them in places where they're useful. You will need to iterate through the elements twice, there's no getting around it.

Comment: Yes, @MarkusMeskanen I have reiterated  the same in my previous comment too `functools.reduce, which essentially is a reduce operation on the list, but internally can be thought of as another for loop`

Answer (score 2):

You can take the product of all elements in the list via [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), and then divide each element in the list with the product using integer division `//`

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

li = [2,4,5]
#Take product of all elements via reduce operation on the list 
mult = reduce(mul, li)
#40

#Divide the product found in the step above by each item via integer division
res = [mult//item for item in li]

print(res)
```

You can also multiply elements in a for loop if you don't want to use `functools.reduce`

```
#Or loop over the element to multiply
mult = 1
for item in li:
    mult *= item
```

The output will be

```
[20, 10, 8]
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation, why this code does the same as original? I doubt OP can follow, otherwise he would probably found out this optimization by himself.

Comment: I have added explanation as inline comments, are those unclear @RadosławCybulski

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question in leetcode I think and there was a constraint to not use division and  still do this algorithm in `O(n)`. Basically I traverse the array two times once in forward direction and once in reverse and the multipies corresponding elements in the third iteration to get the output you see.

```
oldlist = [2,4,5]
forwardlist=[1]*len(oldlist)
backwardlist=[1]*len(oldlist)
mul = oldlist[0]
for i in range(1,len(oldlist)):
    forwardlist[i] = mul
    mul*= oldlist[i]
mul = oldlist[len(oldlist) - 1]
for i in range(len(oldlist) - 2, -1, -1):
    backwardlist[i] = mul
    mul*= oldlist[i]
newlist = []
for i in range(len(oldlist)):
    newlist.append(forwardlist[i]*backwardlist[i])
print(newlist)
```

OUTPUT

```
[20, 10, 8]
```

Hope that was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about just this

```
c = 1
for i in oldList:
    c *= i
newList = [c//e for e in oldList]
```

Now your function will be

```
def mulList():
    oldList = [2,4,5]
    c = 1
    for i in oldList:
        c *= i
    newList = [c//e for e in oldList]
    print(newList)
```